# Discrete J-method of interpolation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, interpolation-spaces

The discrete $J$ method is, given Banach spaces $A_0$ and $A_1$:

> The interpolationn space $[A_0, A_1]_\theta$ is defined by: $a \in [A_0, A_1]_\theta$ if and only if $a$ can be written as $a=\sum_{k \geq 1}a_k$ where the series converges in $A_0 + A_1$, where each $a_k$ belongs to $A_0 \cap A_1$ and where $(2^{-j\theta} J(2^j, a_j)) \in \ell^2$.

Here $J(t,\cdot)$ is a norm and irrelevant to my question. (Eg. see page 16 of [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Rjn1NqO959sC&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=discrete+j-method+interpolation&source=bl&ots=EhMsh7cwPn&sig=FVIJcNEDo12AaruElTLPW6ygIas&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3bq6VL-vBYKv7AbI8IGoBg&ved=0CCIQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=discrete%20j-method%20interpolation&f=false))

Suppose I have an element $u \in [A_0, A_1]_\theta$ and I know that it can be written as 
$$u=\sum_j {u_j},$$
where $u_j$ is known.

I want to apply the theorem. Since $u \in [A_0, A_1]_\theta$, the theorem states it can be written as $u=\sum_{k \geq 1}a_k$ for some $a_k$. Can I pick $a_k = u_k$? I want to do this so that if so, I know the sequence $(2^{-j\theta} J(2^j, u_j))$ is in $\ell^2,$ which is the result that I want.

Or is this $a_k$ sequence not known?

Originally posted https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109371/discrete-j-method-of-interpolation-about-understanding-theorem-statement.

Comment: What do you know about the functions $u_j$ and in which sense does the series $\sum_ju_j$ converge?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta we have $u=\sum_j {u_j} = \sum_j (u,w_j)w_j$ where $w_j$ is an o.n basis of $A_0$ and an orthogonal basis of $A_1$. The sum converges in $A_0$. Suppose that $A_1 \subset A_0$.